# OpenWrt UEFI boot extremely slow?

Tags: boot, uefi, openwrt

I tried to install a thrid-party OpenWrt image to a computer. After writing the image file to SSD and start booting, the kernel message prints at a really slow pace, although some of the timestamp seems to be normal.

Here is the result of dmesg. The printing pace is mostly of 2 seconds for one line, but the timestamp only increased few milliseconds. As it's too long I posted it to Pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZJKfXfGDSk/

Is that normal? It takes me about 5 minutes to complete the whole booting process. Once it boots, it works flawlessly. Also this phenomenon won't happen when using Legacy boot mode and the booting process takes about 6 seconds before you can press enter to access the console.

Comment: @Johan Myréen Please add as an answer so I can select as the best answer. That's exactly what the problem is. Thanks so much.

Comment: may I ask you how you got Openwrt to boot on UEFI?

Comment: @Mehdi I am using an 3rd party source and it comes with _Build EFI GRUB images (Linux x86 or x86_64 host only)_ in the  target image options. I believe there is no such option in the official source.

Comment: can you please provide a link to that third party source? What I found now to be efi compatible is a still open pull request in the official github repository and another version from JOW https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt/staging/jow.git

Comment: @Mehdi Here it is: https://github.com/coolsnowwolf/lede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `console=ttyS0,115200n8r` from the kernrl command line so the kernel doesn't try to write messages to the serial port, which is slowing down the boot.